# How to find element using xpath or css selector in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to click a button for a drop-down menu.

This is drop-down button for toggle. If I click on the button, it will drop-down and show an option. If the button is clicked again, the display will change back to original.

...

```
<div f-menu-item-submenu="$parent.createMenu" ng-if="!$root.ADMIN_RO &amp;&amp; menu.menuBar" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope menu-item menu-item-submenu">
    <button type="button" ng-class="{'selected': selected}" ng-disabled="disabled()" ng-click="onClick($event)">
        <div class="flex-button-content" ng-transclude="">
            <f-icon class="ftnt-add ng-scope"></f-icon><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                Create New
            </span><span class="flex-filler"></span><f-icon class="fa-caret-down toggle-indicator">
            </f-icon>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

First I try to find the element by using xpath:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/nav/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span")
```

The Python says:

```
"Unable to locate element".
```

Then I try to find the element by using CSS slector:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".left-menu-items > div.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope.menu-item.menu-item-submenu > button > div > span.ng-binding.ng-scope")
```

The selenium still says:

```
"Unable to locate element"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were pretty close with the `css_selector`.

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope.menu-item.menu-item-submenu > button > div.flex-button-content span.ng-binding.ng-scope"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ng-scope ng-isolate-scope menu-item menu-item-submenu']/button/div[@class='flex-button-content']//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(., 'Create New')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPath selector](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) which will rely on this `Create New` text via [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function like:

```
//span[normalize-space()='Create New']
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPATH is:

```
//div[@class='ng-scope ng-isolate-scope menu-item menu-item-submenu']/button
```

You'll need just that to click the button.